# Set currentPage using dialog property in Adobe AEM

Tags: adobe, aem, sightly, htl

I am creating a menu component. Mouting a tree with the pages and its children.

```html
<ul class="topnav" data-sly-list.child="${currentPage.listChildren}">
```

It's working fine, but I need to replace the `currentPage` using a property of my **dialog** component.

How can I do this?

I already have the dialog component and I'm able to retrieve the property value.

[image]

> I don't wanna use java classes, I am assuming that there's a way to do
>   this using only htl

Comment: I can understand why you want to stick to HTL only solution but not using POJO classes to model this (business) requirement of yours will be a hacked solution. I strongly recommend not following this path. Just an advise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no shorthand for getting a `Page` specified by a path, mostly because HTL sits lower than the WCM layer in AEM.

You can find an example of how to do this using the Use-API (JS, but it's similar in Java) at https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/aem-htl-repl/blob/master/content-pkg/jcr_root/apps/repl/components/repl/template.html and https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/aem-htl-repl/blob/master/content-pkg/jcr_root/apps/repl/components/repl/logic.js

Comment: I'm running some tests based on the code you suggested.

Comment: It worked, but not exactly as I expected. When I change to design_dialog, the component (I don't know how/why) can't get the property value. But the simple dialog works fine for me